# My computer will not turn on

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

I recently built a gaming PC. It was working fine before the following events: I installed a graphics card driver update then: in Windows it said that the User Experience Index needed to be refreshed, so I started the test and somewhere in the middle of the test my PC just switched off. No shutting down, it just stopped.

Now it won't turn back on. I have checked it's plugged in and the on/off switch on the PSU is on, I tried a different power cable, and I checked all the connections. When I press the power button nothing happens, no fans, no lights, no POST beep.

**Specifications:**
• Motherboard: Gigabyte GA78LMT-USB3
• CPU: AMD FX-6350 3.9GHz
• RAM: 2x4GB Crucial Ballistix Sport
• Power supply: Tesla 750W
• Graphics card: XFX Radeon 7870 DD
• Case: CiT Vantage R Gaming Case
• Hard drive: 2TB Western Digital Caviar Green

Please help me. This computer is only a week old since I built it. All answers are appreciated. :)

Comment: Yeah, likely either your PS or graphics card is fried.  But of course the first thing to try is unplugging and re-plugging everything.

Comment: If it is indeed fried, your components are almost certainly still in warranty (according to what you said, only a week old) so you should contact customer support for the defective component (when you figure out which one it is) and get a replacement.

Comment: Also, what sort of noise did it make as the power cut off? That can be rather important, if it was different from the normal switch off noise.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you PSU is fried.

Try disconnecting it from your computer, and short-circuit between the green wire and a black one on the ATX power plug to the motherboard - if the fan won't start then your PSU is definitely fried.

If it does start, then try disconnecting your graphics card and starting your computer.